# how to put a condition on row for the records if the value is present then take other column value otherwise null?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example my df contains below data :

Part,Res_val,res_date,id,mass,start,sec_id ( COLUMNS ) AND BELOW ARE VALUES.

```
Part,res_value,res_date,id,sample_number,start,sec_id

ABC1,4,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC2,2,01/07/2022 11:27:43,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC3,3,01/06/2022 08:12:39,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC1,4,01/06/2022 08:12:39,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC2,5,01/10/2022 15:15:14,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC3,2,01/11/2022 17:28:56,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
ABC1,2,01/11/2022 17:28:56,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234

ABC1,4,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC2,10,01/07/2022 11:27:43,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC3,3,01/06/2022 08:12:39,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC1,4,01/06/2022 08:12:39,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC2,5,01/10/2022 15:15:14,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC3,2,01/11/2022 17:28:56,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
ABC1,2,01/11/2022 17:28:56,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
```

Result :

ABC1_result,ABC2_result,res_date,id,sample_number,start,sec_id

```
4,2,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
4,10,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
```

I want to select recent row based on time and I want to check if the  sec_id having part ABC1 or ABC2 then I will take res_value respectively for that row otherwise the column would be null

So the output should look like :
ABC1_result,ABC2_result,res_date,id,sample_number,start,sec_id

```
4,2,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK123,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ234
4,10,01/10/2022 15:15:15,GKK122,1,2022-10-03 19:35:14,AHJ233
```

Comment: What means ` I want to check if the sec_id having part ABC1 or ABC2` ? It means all values has `A`, so match all rows?

Comment: In the data we have multiple rows with sec_id, I want to select latest sec id and in that row I need to add ABC1_result and ABC2_result column

Answer (score 1):

If need test `Part` if match list and then need pivoting use:

```
L = ['ABC1','ABC3']

df1 = df[df['Part'].isin(L)].set_index(['Part'], append=True)['Res_val'].unstack().add_prefix('Res_val_')
df = pd.concat([df1, df.drop(['Part','Res_val'], axis=1)], axis=1)
print (df)
   Res_val_ABC1  Res_val_ABC3             res_date    id  mass  \
0           1.0           NaN  09/11/2002 16:14:12  A458     5   
1           NaN           NaN  05/04/2002 10:23:43  A352     6   
2           NaN           6.0  05/06/2002 09:18:39  B425     7   

                 start sec_id  
0  2002-16-07 23:35:14  530HQ  
1  2002-14-05 12:56:14  2345T  
2  2002-14-03 12:12:56   25F2
```

If need top values per list by datetimes use:

```
df['res_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['res_date'], dayfirst=True)

L = ['ABC1','ABC2']

df1 = df[df['Part'].isin(L)].sort_values(['sec_id','res_date']).drop_duplicates(['Part','sec_id'])
print (df1)
    Part  res_value            res_date      id  sample_number  \
10  ABC1          4 2022-06-01 08:12:39  GKK122        1   
8   ABC2         10 2022-07-01 11:27:43  GKK122        1   
3   ABC1          4 2022-06-01 08:12:39  GKK123        1   
1   ABC2          2 2022-07-01 11:27:43  GKK123        1   

                  start  sec_id  
10  2022-10-03 19:35:14  AHJ233  
8   2022-10-03 19:35:14  AHJ233  
3   2022-10-03 19:35:14  AHJ234  
1   2022-10-03 19:35:14  AHJ234
```

Because same values per groups by `sec_id` is possible pivoting like:

```
df2 = (df1.pivot(index=['id','start','sample_number','sec_id'], 
                 columns='Part', 
                 values='res_value')
          .add_suffix('_res_value')
          .reset_index())

print (df2)
Part      id                start  sample_number  sec_id  ABC1_res_value  \
0     GKK122  2022-10-03 19:35:14        1 AHJ233               4   
1     GKK123  2022-10-03 19:35:14        1  AHJ234               4   

Part  ABC2_res_value  
0                 10  
1                  2
```

Comment: Thanks, But iam getting the multiple rows sec_id, I need only one

Comment: @David - Can you check sedond solution? Not sure with datetimes columns, so omited.